# Rails find method hanging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, find

New to rails and a bit confused.

I have the following condition:

```
if Agency.find(params[:agency]).id
  @parent = Agency.find(params[:agency]).id
end
```

It hangs on the first line and returns the error, **"Couldn't find Agency without an ID"**.. which is my point to begin with...

If it cannot find the agency then it shouldn't do anything (at least that was my intention). Otherwise set the @parent instance.

What is the proper syntax for checking whether it can find it (an agency) to being with?

**EDIT:**

Searching the docs I realized this,

**"The find method will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception unless a matching record is found for all of the supplied primary keys."**

Comment: show the value of `params[:agency]` ?

Comment: Awesome.. this worked.. if you want to answer it I'll give credit.

Comment: I don't know how I helped.. :-) But you got what wrong you did, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to set the `@parent` variable if the Agency record exists, check for its existance first with `exists?`

```
if Agency.exists?(params[:agency])
  @parent = Agency.find(params[:agency]).id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, the find method requires the id as a parameter. If you have a column called agency in your Agency model you could use find_by, eg. `Agency.find_by(agency: params[:agency]).id`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the docs and @aruprakshit, I realized why I wasn't checking this properly to begin with.

the docs state, **"The find method will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception unless a matching record is found for all of the supplied primary keys."** http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

I didn't try simply looking at `params[:agency]` as was suggested to see if it actually existed. After adjusting my code to the following:

```
if Agency.exists?(params[:agency])
  @parent = Agency.find(params[:agency]).id
end
```

It worked like a charm.